# Retrofit Post request doesn't get response from Server Android

Tags: android, post, retrofit, okhttp

I'm getting the response from the Okhttp Logging interceptor in the Log cat. But I'm unable to get it in the retrofit response from the post call.
Here is my post call:

```
private void update(PostEntity postEntity){
    Call<ResponseEntity> call = baseProvider.getApiClient().
            createNewQuestion(mPrefs.getLoggedUserCityId(), postEntity);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseEntity>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseEntity> call, Response<ResponseEntity> response) {
            Log.i("post:", response.body().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseEntity> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.i("Not Working", "Retrofit is not updating the feed!!");
        }
    });
}
```

D/OkHttp: OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1471598299803 
D/OkHttp: OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1471598300522 
D/OkHttp: {"message":"Posted Successfully","uuid":"5dgiriWE4s4Sqhts"}

Here I get response.body().toString is OK. I'm unable to get the okhttp interceptor output, to store the uuid from the server.

Comment: is it going to the failure method

Comment: @Soham No it's a success call, it's going into the onResponse only. But the response doesn't have anything, which is shown in the logcat by the Okhttp interceptor.

Comment: what is ResponseEntity ?

Comment: It's just a model, which I have created. Doesn't belong to retrofit or okhttp. It contains 2 strings, message, uuid which I can extract from the response of retrofit actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I am assuming that `response.body().toString()` will return something like

```
ResponseEntity("message":"Posted Successfully","uuid":"5dgiriWE4s4Sqhts")
```

So if you want to extract the values for example if you want to get `uuid` from this you have to do like below (assuming your `ResponseEntity` class have `getter` and `setter` methods)

```
String udid=(ResponseEntity)(response.body()).getUDID()
```

Hope you will get an idea from this.

Comment: that is the problem! I can see the response in the log which is given by the okhttp logging interceptor. But in the retrofit response.body() I don't get anything as I mentioned. I'm getting response@54393 something which isn't what I want

Comment: yeah, kind of, you helped a bit. Thanks. I have chosen your answer

Comment: @RahulN please accept the answer.It will help others to view the answer.